# Convert String from csv file to datetime object with extra character using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, parsing

I have a csv file with the following format :

```
20220904 182409 7579480;1000;1100;1200;1300
20220904 220000 0480000;1000;1100;1200;1300
20220904 220000 0760000;1000;1100;1200;1300
```

Note that I have an extra "0" at the end of the nanoseconds....

I read the csv file using pandas and convert the first column which has a label of "Time" to a `datetime` object:

```
def myparser(x):
   return pd.to_datetime(x, format='%Y%m%d %H%M%S %f0')


Data = pd.read_csv(Path,
                       sep=";",
                       header=None,
                       names=['Time','A','B','C','D'],
                       parse_dates=['Time'],
                       date_parser=myparser)
```

This code worked fine until I found some data to have a value other than "0" as the extra character! like this:

```
20220904 182409 7106549;1000;1100;1200;1300
```

what should I do to make my `myparser`  read the other characters as well? (here it is a "9") I actually do not need the character value. As long as I am concerned, converting the strings to `datetime` would do the job.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Dear @FObersteiner Thanks for your solution. I suppose that I have to follow your suggestion, after I have read the data into the `Dataframe`, however, I am looking for converting the 'Time' column to `datetime` object `inplace`. I have no idea how to follow your solution `inplace`.  Can you give me a hint to do that as I read the csv file?

Comment: Actually, I'll have to revise my initial comments. Supplying the format with `%f` works just fine for me; you can do that as short as `date_parser=lambda s: pd.to_datetime(s, format='%Y%m%d %H%M%S %f')`. Doing this even keeps precision of the 7th digit (instead of truncating to microseconds).

Answer (score 0):

In test input data with and without `0` is same length of nanoseconds:

```
20220904 182409 7579480;1000;1100;1200;1300
20220904 220000 0480000;1000;1100;1200;1300
20220904 220000 0760000;1000;1100;1200;1300
20220904 182409 7106549;1000;1100;1200;1300
```

so if remove `0` it should working same like solution with parse without `0`:

```
temp="""20220904 182409 7579480;1000;1100;1200;1300
20220904 220000 0480000;1000;1100;1200;1300
20220904 220000 0760000;1000;1100;1200;1300
20220904 182409 7106549;1000;1100;1200;1300
"""


def myparser(x):
    return pd.to_datetime(x, format='%Y%m%d %H%M%S %f')
    

Data = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp),
                       sep=";",
                       header=None,
                       names=['Time','A','B','C','D'],
                       parse_dates=['Time'],
                       date_parser=myparser)

print (Data)

                           Time     A     B     C     D
0 2022-09-04 18:24:09.757948000  1000  1100  1200  1300
1 2022-09-04 22:00:00.048000000  1000  1100  1200  1300
2 2022-09-04 22:00:00.076000000  1000  1100  1200  1300
3 2022-09-04 18:24:09.710654900  1000  1100  1200  1300
```

---

```
def myparser(x):
    try:
        return pd.to_datetime(x, format='%Y%m%d %H%M%S %f0')
    except:
        return pd.to_datetime(x, format='%Y%m%d %H%M%S %f')
    

Data = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp),
                       sep=";",
                       header=None,
                       names=['Time','A','B','C','D'],
                       parse_dates=['Time'],
                       date_parser=myparser)

print (Data)
                           Time     A     B     C     D
0 2022-09-04 18:24:09.757948000  1000  1100  1200  1300
1 2022-09-04 22:00:00.048000000  1000  1100  1200  1300
2 2022-09-04 22:00:00.076000000  1000  1100  1200  1300
3 2022-09-04 18:24:09.710654900  1000  1100  1200  1300
```

Comment: Thanks. As long as I remember when writing the code and as stated [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) the `%f` is zeropadded to 6 digits, so I get an error if there is an extra digit there. Can you help me on this? If your first solution works, why should bother and defining the parser using a `try` command?

Comment: @ShK - I can explain - I want to show same ouput if use `try-except` or second solution. What is expected ouput from your data?

Comment: Thanks. What I expect is a column with `datetime` format. What is the result of using `format='%Y%m%d %H%M%S %f` if I have extra digits after six  expected digits?  I shall try this myself however.